# Equivalence between a geometric distribution and the hitting time for level 1 of a random walk that only goes up.

Tags: probability, generating-functions, intuition

Let $0<p=1-q,r<1$ be fixed probabilities, and $X_i,i=1,2,\dots$ be i.i.d. random variables with the following distribution:
$$
X_i=
\begin{cases}
1,&\text{with probability }rp,\\
0,&\text{with probability }1-r,\\
-1,&\text{with probability }rq.
\end{cases}
$$
Define
$$
S_0=0,\quad S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\quad(n>0).
$$
This is a random walk that only moves with probability $r$, and stays put with probability $1-r$ at each step. Define the hitting time of level $1$ as usual:
$$
\tau^+:=\inf\{n>0\:S_n=1\}.
$$

Prove, for $0<s<1$,
$$
P^+(s)=\frac{1-(1-r)s-\sqrt{((1-r)s-1)^2-4r^2pqs^2}}{2rqs}.\label{eq1}\tag{1}
$$

Give a probabilistic interpretation of the form of $\eqref{eq1}$ of $P^+(s)$ of $\tau^+$ using the Geometric$(r)$ generating function
$$
Q(s)=\frac{rs}{1-(1-r)s}.
$$

I have successfully proved equation $\eqref{eq1}$, but I am stuck for the second part. To me, I would expect that if we set $q=0$, that would basically turn $\tau^+$ into a Geometric$(r)$ variable, since it stays at level $0$ with probability $1-r$, and it hits level $1$ with probability $r$, and it is the waiting time until we hit level $1$. However, when I substitute $q=0,p=1$ into my expression for $P^+(s)$, it does not return what I want it to. It seems like the reasonable way to geto to $Q(s)$ from $P^+(s)$ is to actually substitute in $q=1,p=0$, and then to take the reciprocal of this function. However, this does not make any intuitive sense to me, and I can't figure out what this would represent in terms of the random walk hitting level $1$. Why would we take the reciprocal? Why would we set it so that the random walk can only go down, rather than setting it so that it can only go up? Can anybody make sense of this? It seems like a contradiction between the two generating functions. Can anybody motivate why I would substitute in $q=1,p=0$ and then take the reciprocal? The reciprocal part seems especially confusing to me, because
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac1{s^{\tau^+}}\right)=\mathbb{E}(s^{-\tau^+})
$$
would seem to suggest to me that reciprocating the generating function is possibly related to considering the negative of that random variable, but how could we have the negative of a waiting time? Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: "Only moves with probability $4$" is an obvious typo for "Only moves with probability $r$"  I tried to fix it, but that somehow messed up the formula you want to prove, so I rolled it back.

Comment: I tried to edit to fix problem line.  Peculiar event.  When opening edit, line looks okay, but closing results in problem.  Fixed be removing 'Label' expression and replacing by (1).

Comment: Thanks I think it looks okay now? Did either of you have any tips for my question?

Comment: I believe as $q \to 0$ you do get the reduction that you want; in particular I did the calculation for $r=1/2$ and got $\frac{s}{2-s}$ which is what you wanted to get. There is a derivative operation going on in this case, though.

Comment: I am confused please could you help me out a bit more. So for $r=\frac12$, $P^+(s)=\frac{1-\frac12s-\sqrt{(\frac12s-1)^2-pqs^2}}{qs}$. How do we get that the limit of this as $q\to0$ is $\frac s{2-s}$?

Comment: You can identify $h=qs$ and then it is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0)-f(h)}{h}=-f'(0)$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{(s/2-1)^2-(1-x/s)sx}$. Then just take the derivative.

Comment: Ah very good! I don't think I would have ever seen that